# R package and execution time

Tags: r, compilation, package, interpreter

I have developed a big library of functions in R.
For the moment I just load ("source") the functions at the beginning of all my scripts.

I have seen that I can create packages.

My question is: Will that improve the **execution time** of my functions? (by transforming interpreter code into machine language?)

What does the package creation does? Does it creates binaries?

Thanks
fred

Answer (score 14, accepted):

<strike>There isn't an R compiler yet</strike> Packaging your R code won't improve its execution time massively. It also won't create binaries for you - you need to build those from the package tarball (or get CRAN or similar to build them for you). There is now a byte compiler for R and R's packages are now by default byte compiled. Speed improvements are in general modest - don't expect C-like speed.

Packaging R code just does exactly that; it packages the R code, code to be compiled (C Fortran etc), man pages, documentation, tests etc into a standard format that can be distributed to users and installed/built on multiple architectures.

Packages can take advantage of things like lazy loading such that R objects (your functions say) are only loaded when needed, whereas source loads them all into the global environment (by default).

If you don't intend to distribute your code then there are few benefits of packaging just for your own use, but if you do package and write documentation and examples/tests, you might be alerted to changes in the package code that break examples or cause tests to fail. That way you are better informed as to the reliability of your code, even if it is only you using it!

Comment: Building a package is fun, and it "forces" you to document your functions (if you haven't done so yet). The documentation is easily accessed through help(), which is one of the main things I like about R - help is never far away or obscured.

Comment: A package provides a solid framework for managing R code.  I have always found them beneficial once the collection of functions grows beyond one or two sourced R files---even in personal use situations.

Comment: Check out [R-forge](https://r-forge.r-project.org/) for automatically building your package for different OS.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How come when I open the package it looks like binary code?

Comment: @Fred, which package? From where? Packages are just the tarballs on CRAN. CRAN, as a service, provides *binary* packages for Windows and Mac OS X, but these are processed versions of the source, in the main. The big difference is if a package sources contains a `src` directory containing C, C++, or Fortran source code. When the binary is produced from such package tarballs, the C, C++ or Fortran code is compiled into a library or dll. The R source code remains the same.

Comment: @ Gavin Simpson: I have compiled my own packages using a tutorial found on Internet. The result is an archive file that contains a binary that has the extension *.rdb 
Does this compilation enhanced the execution of the code? (appart from the lazy loading)

Comment: @Fred Those are just efficient ways to store the R code and help files, and only in binaries or **installed** tarballs on linux. They aren't compiled in the sense of compiled into machine code. I'm not really familiar with these, but they might be more efficient to load the objects into R than to parse everything (functions are objects) each time you load a package. But to be clear - the R code is **not** compiled and as such it doesn't improve the execution speed of the R code. These files likely improve the efficiency of loading the package, but that is all.

Comment: @GavinSimpson I'm tempted to curate your first paragraph to bring it up to date.  :)